# SQL query can't be executed

Tags: sql

I am working in a test and they said in the correction that this can't be executed, can you pleased explain to me why ? Thanks in advance

```
SELECT SDATE, DISTINCT S_CID
FROM SESSIONS
ORDER BY S_CID, SDATE
```

to explain more:

- `S_CID` : is a foreign key in the table `SESSIONS`, it is the key of the course.
- `SDATE` : is the date of the session

Answer (score 3):

Your `distinct` is in the wrong place:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SDATE, S_CID
FROM SESSIONS
ORDER BY S_CID, SDATE;
```

I think this will do what you want -- get one date and `s_cid` value with no duplicates.

Remember:  `SELECT DISTINCT` is a *statement* in SQL.  The `DISTINCT` (in this case) only modifies `SELECT`.  It does not apply to individual columns, but to all the columns in the `SELECT` list.